# Datastore query parents in many-to-many reference relationshop

Tags: java, google-app-engine, data-modeling, google-cloud-datastore

I have a couple of datastore entities that exist in a many-to-many relationship where the parent has a list of references to the children. We are using Objectify.

```java
@Entity
@Cache
public class Parent {
    @Index
    String name;

    private List<Ref<Child>> children;
...getters/setters etc...
}

@Entity
@Cache
public class Child {
    @Index
    String name;
...getters/setters etc...
}
```

I need to get a list of all children and a list of all of the parents for each child. Is this the right way to setup my relationship? What does the query look like?

I can get a list of all children and a list of all parents and then loop through each to see which relationships exist but I am wondering if there is a better approach.

Comment: Your question has a contradiction. "a list of all children" AND "a list of all of the parents for each child" means a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: You are right. I will update my question. That is what happens when you don't pay attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can list relationships in one of the entities. Then you can get the list of either parents or children directly from an entity, and the other relationship through a query on this indexed property.

There are only two issues you have to keep in mind:

1. Indexing a property which is a list of values can be tricky - read about exploding indexes. If this entity has many other indexed fields, it's not a good option.
2. Every time you update a relationship, each indexed property in this entity will have to be re-written, which can be very expensive if relationships are updated frequently and/or you have other indexed properties in this entity.

If you do run into these issues, you may consider creating a new entity "Relationship", with one indexed property for a child ID. This entity can be a child entity of a parent entity. With this approach you can get a list of all children by running an ancestor query on Relationship entity, and you can get a list of all parents by running a simple query on Relationship entity with a filter to match child ID (parent ID can be extracted from entities that this query returns by calling `getParent().getId()`).